# how do i make it so that zooming in on the android doesnt change the size of the text

Tags: android, css

I am making CSS voice bubbles, and I fit the text to the bubbles using em to set the text size, but now when I zoom in the text changes size too and it overflows out of the bubble.  I don't want to set the text size with px because I want it to be cross-browser accessible, so is there a way to make it so the text doesn't scale itself to always fit the screen?

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use % instead of em.

here is the article http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/